# Hover one div make another div appear

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover

Here is the site I'm working on: [revistapuerto](http://revistapuerto.net)

It's a Wordpress based site. What I'm trying to achieve through CSS, is to get the excerpt to appear over the picture when you hover over the Title of the post. Right now, the excerpt appears when you hover over the picture only. Want to keep that effect, and add the Title thing.

The picture - excerpt effect I got it from another user here, and here is the CSS in case it helps:

```
#magia {
    position: relative;
}
#magia img {
    display: block;
}
#magia .cornerLink {
    width:494px;
    height:330px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
#magia:hover .cornerLink {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think your best bet will be to use some JS for this.

Comment: As I understand it you are trying hover over an element and have another element **higher up in the DOM** appear. Unfortunately, that's not possible with CSS just yet. Javascript / Jquery is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly the question isn't very clear, you're gonna need to give more information. All I can really offer in regards to what you've asked is basic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MBLZx/

HTML:

```
<div class="showhim">HOVER ME
    <div class="showme">hai</div>
    <div class="ok">ok</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.showme{ 
    display: none;
}
.showhim:hover .showme{
    display : block;
}
.showhim:hover .ok{
    display : none;
}
```

(also the website won't load for me, could just be my work computer!)

that shows how to use hidden divs to make divs appear using a hover.

More information and I might be able to help you out :)

Comment: I didn't went too much into details here, because I think with the website, it was self explanatory. I used your fiddle to figure out what was wrong with my code, I didn't have both divs inside a "bigger" div. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want, here's how you can achieve it.

```
 #div-for-hover:hover #Div-you-want-to-show {
   display: block;
 }
```

The method is simple: The block of CSS code simply says when you hover of **#div-for-hover**, I'll show **#Div-you-want-to-show**

**Note:** The hover could be on a headings, DIVs, images, and more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already figured out what was wrong using the code from @Shaun.